# Do I need to evaluate exact value of $A^9$ to find $Det.(2A^9B^{-1})$?

Tags: matrices

Do I need to evaluate exact value of $A^9$ to find $Det.(2A^9B^{-1})$?
Actually $A=[\begin{matrix}32\\21\end{matrix}],B=[\begin{matrix}31\\73\end{matrix}]$

Comment: The determinant of a product is the product of the determinants.

Comment: Do you know anything relating the determinant of a product of matrices to the determinants of the matrices themselves?

Comment: (But be careful - the determinant of $cA$ is _not_ $c$ times the determinant of $A$ if $c$ is a scalar)

Comment: Check the question: B is not invertiable and A can not be squared

Comment: @belgi why do you say that?  The determinant of B is $3\cdot3-7\cdot1=2$.  (The entries are presumably $(3,1)$ and $(7,3)$, not $31$ and $73$...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided we are dealing with square matrices, then $\det(A B) = \det(A) \det(B)$. Thus,
$$\det(2 I A^9 B^{-1}) = \det(2 I) \det(A)^9 \det(B)^{-1}.$$
So no, you don't need to compute $A^9$ or even $B^{-1}$ for that matter.

Further hint: Be careful finding $\det(2I)$. It is probably not what you think it is.